# choosing value of δ and ε to prove uniform discontinuity

Tags: calculus

To prove that a function $f(x)$ is not uniform continuous , all we need to prove is :
$∃\epsilon >0$ $\forall \delta>0$ $\exists x,y \ni |x−y|<\delta and |f(x)−f(y)|≥\epsilon.$

If we prove this choosing two points for $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \to |f(x)−f(y)|\implies \epsilon$ , then we are done. What my doubt is we must choose $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\delta$ and then give a value to $\delta$ such that the values of $x$ and $y$ lie in the domain of $f$ (with $\delta$ chosen in a way such that its greater than 0 ofcourse) . and then we prove $|f(x)−f(y)|\geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon  > 0$. Does the value of $\epsilon$ chosen must also lie in the range of the function?????. According to what i have learnt upto now, i guess thats not necessary.We can choose any value of $\epsilon$ even if its not in the range of $f$ so as to prove $|f(x)−f(y)|\geq \epsilon$ , the only condition being $\epsilon >0$. Am i right on this? If not, then where i am getting wrong and why...Thanks for your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove continuity, you are given $x$ and $\epsilon$ and have to find a $\delta$ that works.  To prove uniform continuity, you are given an $\epsilon$ and have to find a $\delta$ that works for all $x$.  A good example is $f(x)=\frac 1x$.  Since $\frac d{dx} \frac 1x=-\frac 1{x^2}$ you can take $\delta=\frac \epsilon{2x^2}$ and it works.  As $x$ gets close to zero, $\delta$ is smaller and smaller.

Comment: thanks...got to know it now...:)

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the only condition is that $\epsilon > 0$.

It would probably be a good idea to work out an example. Let's consider $f:(-\infty,0) \to \mathbf{R}$ define by $f(x) = 1/x$. This function is continuous, but not uniformly continuous. Choose $\epsilon =1$. (Notice $1$ is not in the range of $f$. This is fine $\epsilon$ itself does not represent a value of $f$; it is used to measure the closeness of values of $f$.) Let $\delta$ be given. Now just choose $x$ and $y$ to both be really small compared to $\delta$, say $x=-\delta/10$ and $y=-\delta/20$. (Note that here we must take the minus sign because $x$ and $y$ must be chosen the domain. It doesn't make sense to require the function to be smooth outside its domain.) Then $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is $10/\delta$, which is greater than $\epsilon = 1$ for sufficiently small $\delta$. This shows the function is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: thanks for your feedback....